# Is "all that he have" correct?

Tags: conjugation

Should I say "All the things he have will be given to her" or "All the things he has will be given to her" ?

Comment: That's a shortened way of saying "all the things that he <to have> ", so the 'to have' is associated with 'he' so should be singular. So "all the things that __he has__... "

Comment: You could say something like "A man must give all that he have" as a rather dated use of the subjunctive, which would mean, roughly, "A man must give all that he might have." But @Mitch is correct that normal modern usage would be to use the indicative and so the third-person singular *has* would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern English, "All the things he have" is not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

"All the things he has will be given to her" is correct. "Has" is the third-person singular form of the verb "to have" and it could be substituted for any other 3rd-person singular, e.g. "all the things he owns will be given to her".

Comment: All the things that he halves will be given to her.:)