# She had more experience than I, she having [...] or her having [...]

Tags: grammaticality

Is it

> He had more experience than I, *he* having produced more than 10 songs already.

or

> He had more experience than I, *him* having produced more than 10 songs already.

The latter sounds more natural to me, but the former seems more grammatically consistent—alas I don't know what the parts are called to delve further. The questions [Is "all that he have" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60250/is-all-that-he-have-correct) and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119167/he-have-a-point-is-this-correct were all I could find and didn't seem specifically relevant, AFAICT.

Comment: neither. _Having produced more than 10 songs already, he had more experience than I_ - or _He had more experience than I, having produced less than his 10 songs_

Comment: @mplungjan, your second example does not make sense. The participle modifies the subject of the sentence, so it would mean that he had produced less than his own ten songs. “He had more experience than I/me, having produced more than ten songs already” is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Young's Literal Translation of the Bible contains:

> [Luke 15]: 13 `And not many days after, having gathered all together,
>   the younger son went abroad to a far country, and there he scattered
>   his substance, living riotously; 14 and he having spent all, there
>   came a mighty famine on that country, and himself began to be in
>   want...

But I'd agree that the inclusion of the 'he' is archaic (not 'wrong!') here.

However, I wouldn't quibble about the following example (B) of the usage:

> (A) John and Jennie each had more experience than I / me, John (*for instance*) having produced more than 10 songs already.

...

> (B) John and his sister each had more experience than I / me, he having
>   produced more than 10 songs already.

(Add the 'for instance' in A / B if you wish - it's logical.)

Comment: In your examples with two people, where the pronoun disambiguates, it is natural enough. In the asker’s examples, though, I find it unnatural in contemporary English.

Comment: Yes. I thought I'd covered that. Though OP queried the grammaticality rather than the idiomaticity.

Comment: Thank you for finding that passage. The use of "he" actually doesn't sound too archaic to me, and this is for my own writing, so with the vote of confidence (that "he" isn't _wrong_), I think I'll use "he."

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions as answer instead of comment with correction

Neither. The first, albeit possibly correct, sounds weird/archaic

- Having produced more than 10 songs already, he had more experience than I
- He had more experience than I, having produced more than 10 songs already.

Comment: Thanks; your second suggestion is where I _started_, but I wasn't satisfied with the (syntactic) ambiguity of _who_ "produced more than 10 songs already." I do like your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gerund phrase, so the usual recommendation is actually possessive:

> …his having produced…

However, I usually hear the object form (me/you/him/her/us/them) in speech:

> …without me being aware…

In your specific case, though, I would omit the pronoun altogether:

> He had more experience than I, having produced more than 10 songs already.

Comment: The usual recommendation, in my opinion, is 'use the form that achieves the meaning or emphasis you want': **I didn't see him dancing** just states the fact you didn't see him performing (he may not have danced); / **I didn't see his dancing** states the fact that you missed his routine. Both are perfectly grammatical. The first variant of _dancing_ lies nearer the verbal end of the spectrum, the second nearer the nounal.

Comment: @JonPurdy - Thanks for the suggestion; that's actually where I _started_, but wasn't satisfied with the (syntactic) ambiguity of _who_ "produced more than 10 songs already."